# Question About Collisions Between Neutrons

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum, energy-conservation, collision

I came across this question from AP Classroom that asked something along the lines of,

> Neutron A was traveling at velocity: $v$ and has wavelength $\lambda$. It then hit neutron B and after the collision both protons were traveling at velocity: $v'$ each. What is the new wavelength of neutron A?

So I initially decided to use the conservation of momentum.

$$mv=mv'+mv' \Rightarrow v=2v' \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2} v=v' $$

The equation $\lambda=\frac hp$ states that halving the momentum would double the wavelength thus the new wavelength should be $2\lambda$.

It turns out that the answer was actually $\sqrt{2} \lambda$. The explanation stated that since this is a collision between neutrons, kinetic energy was conserved, so

$$v^2=2v'^2 \Rightarrow \frac {1}{\sqrt 2}v=v' $$

And because of the previous equation decreasing momentum by $\sqrt 2$ would increase wavelength by that amount giving you the answer of $\sqrt{2} \lambda$.

What went wrong when I used the conservation of momentum? From what I understand, all collisions must adhere to that law.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please add this tag to this type of problem. This is one of the things that we ask you to do in our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: Please reference the source of this homework question. This is one of the things that we ask you to do in our homework policy: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not told that the collision happens in 1D, and momentum is a vector quantity. So it is true that 
$$m\mathbf v_0=m\mathbf v_A+m\mathbf v_B$$
where $|\mathbf v_A|=|\mathbf v_B|=v'$. But it is not true in general that $mv=2mv'$. In fact, you have shown that for the specific elastic collision here the collision *cannot* be in 1D, as we would not be able to conserve both momentum and energy in this way (the collision can actually occur in 2D though).

However, kinetic energy is a scalar quantity. So, if you know your initial kinetic energy and final kinetic energy, and you know the collision is elastic, then you can use $K_\text{init}=K_\text{final}$ without having to worry about the direction of the velocities.